# The solution use Thevenin's theorem to solve the problem,but i can't understand why

Tags: voltage, current, thevenin

This solution use Thevenin's theorem to solve the problem,but i can't really understand its meaning ,hoping someone can explain them to me!

Question:determine the I value

[image]

Sol:

[image]

\$R_{th}=2//4=\frac{4}{3}=1.333\$,\$//\$ means parallel

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE1t8O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_x=(4//2)(2+\frac{-10}{2})=-4\$,where does \$\frac{-10}{2}\$ come from?i don't understand!

\$V_A-V_B=-4 \times \frac{1}{2}-(-10)=8\$,where does \$\frac{1}{2}\$ come from?i don't understand!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foW5pe.png)</sup>

\$I=\frac{14}{\frac{7}{3}}=6A\$

Comment: Nodal analysis at node \$V_x\$ gives: \$\frac{V_x +10}{2}-2+\frac{V_x}{4}=0\$

Answer (score -1):

> where does \$ \frac{−10}{2}\$ come from? I don't understand!

When the author tries to find \$V_X\$ voltage he simply converts the voltage source to a current source.
[image]

Also, you should always track the units, in this case, you will see that \$\frac{10V}{2\Omega} = 5A\$ has a unit of amperes.

$$ V_X = (2A - 5A) \times 4\Omega||2\Omega =-4V $$

> where does 1/2 come from? I don't understand!

Again you don't track the units and this is why you don't see what is going on.

So, we have this situation:

[image]

And we want to know the voltage difference between two points \$A\$ and \$B\$

We see that the voltage at point \$B\$ is equal to \$-10V\$ with respect to ground.

So, we need to find the voltage at point \$A\$ also with respect to ground.

But this is not a problem because we already know the voltage at point \$V_X\$.

The current that will flow via \$R_2 + R_3\$ is equal to:

$$I = \frac{V_X}{R_2 + R_3} = -1A$$

And the voltage at point \$A\$ is

$$V_A = I \times R_3 =\frac{V_X}{R_2 + R_3} \times R_3 = V_X \times \frac{R_3}{R_2 + R_3} = -4V \times \frac{2\Omega}{2\Omega + 2\Omega} = -4V \times \frac{2\Omega}{4\Omega} =$$

$$ = -4V \times \frac{1\Omega}{2\Omega} = -2V$$

Therefore:

$$V_{AB} = V_A - V_B = (-2V) - (-10V) = 8V$$